# Phaser.io button callback not triggering (TypeScript, VSCode)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, phaser-framework

I've followed the template listed on this website, which has worked perfectly: http://divillysausages.com/2015/06/09/using-phaser-with-visual-studio-code/.

I then tried to add a button to the game in the create method:

```
class SimpleGame
{
    game :Phaser.Game;

    constructor()
    {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', {preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update});
    }

    preload()
    {
        this.game.load.spritesheet('button', 'assets/button-round-a.png', 64, 64);
    }

    create()
    {
        var button = this.game.add.button(0, 0, 'button', this.onButtonPress, this);
    }

    update()
    {
    }

    onButtonPress()
    {
        console.log('Here!');
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var game = new SimpleGame();
}
```

The button indeed appears as expected, but pressing it does nothing. The generated JS is this:

```
var SimpleGame = (function () {
    function SimpleGame() {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update });
    }
    SimpleGame.prototype.preload = function () {
        this.game.load.spritesheet('button', 'assets/button-round-a.png', 64, 64);
    };
    SimpleGame.prototype.create = function () {
        var button = this.game.add.button(0, 0, 'button', this.onButtonPress, this);
    };
    SimpleGame.prototype.update = function () {
    };
    SimpleGame.prototype.onButtonPress = function () {
        console.log('Here!');
    };
    return SimpleGame;
})();
window.onload = function () {
    var game = new SimpleGame();
};
```

I've tried messing around with this and doing other weird stuff, but then it calls the function undefined. Basically, the callback isn't triggered at all. I've tried to insert the intended functionality right in the method call, and it works, but I don't want to keep it there. Any help would be huge :D :D :D.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!
Instead of

```
this.onButtonPress
```

I had to use

```
SimpleGame.prototype.onButtonPress
```